# Google Map on HTML page doesnt work anymore

Tags: html, dictionary

I had a google map in my index page and it was working. I checked it now and its not working anymore. Is there something wrong with the code?

```
<!-- Set height and width with CSS -->
<div id="googleMap" style="height:600px;width:100%;"></div>

<!-- Add Google Maps -->
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.878114, -87.629798);

function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:myCenter,
zoom:12,
scrollwheel:false,
draggable:true,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position:myCenter,
});

marker.setMap(map);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your project is live on server then it required api key if offline that supposed to work.

Loading the Google Maps JavaScript API

To load the Google Maps JavaScript API, use a script tag like the one in the following example:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>

The URL contained in the script tag is the location of a JavaScript file that loads all of the symbols and definitions you need for using the Maps
```

JavaScript API. This script tag is required.

The async attribute lets the browser render the rest of your website while the Maps JavaScript API loads. When the API is ready, it will call the function specified using the callback parameter.

The key parameter contains your application's API key. See Get a Key for more information.

Note: Google Maps APIs Premium Plan customers may use either an API key or a valid client ID when loading the API. Get more information on authentication parameters for Premium Plan customers.